# how to see what font is actually being used

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Say I have a span element on a website that has `font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,segoe ui,Roboto,helvetica neue,Arial,sans-serif`. As I understand it it'll work it's way through that list until it finds a qualifying font on your local system.

My question is...  is it possible to see what the qualifying font is?

Comment: Possible cross-site (Stack Overflow) duplicate: [How can I determine what font a browser is actually using to render some text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884177/how-can-i-determine-what-font-a-browser-is-actually-using-to-render-some-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out which font is used in any part of a displayed web-page,
use the extension
[WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en),
also available for other browsers.

Just hover over any text in the page, and you will find out instantly
which font is used.